# How can I set transparency of the text box on a table view? (Xcode)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, textbox, transparency

I'm working on a project in Xcode and am trying to add an on/off switch to my table view, but the box used for the text keeps overlapping the on/off controller.
I tried changing the font size but the size of the actually box for the text stayed the same.
Is there a way to either:
Change the size of the text box on the table view
Make the text box transparent
or Specify the layer of objects on the table view (so I can bring the on/off switch forward)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you really want, to set transparency on a view you can change the alpha property :

```
textBox.alpha = 0.5;
```

and to change the frame :

```
textBox.frame = CGRectMake(originx, originy, width, height);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Changing the alpha was close enough of a fix to work for the problem I was having.